# Why won't my user account (with admin privileges) open some programs?

Tags: windows-10, administrator

I recently installed a program using my user account with admin privileges. Notice that I said that I installed it while logged into the user account. So there would have been no reason whatsoever for the program to have been set up to allow a different user. (It is just that user account and the administrator account.) But when I went to open it, it wouldn't open. But it DID open when I right clicked and had it Run as Administrator. Now again, the program would have had no reason to have installed as the Administrator account since I haven't logged into that account since the first week I had this computer, which was months ago. I have never seen an install program install for a user account that wasn't the one that was logged on for the install. It is either Install for this user, or ALL users. But the current user is always one.

So what is going on there? I've used this same install file on 4 previous Windows 10 installations and never had that issue, so it seems like it might be a recent Windows 10 version change. I am actually going to be reinstalling Windows from scratch in the near future because I got a new M.2 drive to boot from, and I always planned on the current install to be temporary and to reinstall from scratch without any bloatware from the computer manufacturer. So, since I sure as heck don't want to keep right clicking on files to open them, should I just start out running under the full blown Administrator account? Supposedly not a good idea to do that, but if Windows is forcing me to be less safe, then I will be less safe.

Comment: I suggest you trying clarifying your question to say the exact problem you are facing. Programs being opened in User A that is a member of Administrators will open different ways depending on the program. There may not be anything wrong.

Comment: _Install for This User_ || _Install for All Users_ usually only affects which `Start Menu` directory the shortcuts are placed within _(either `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` or `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`)_, occasionally affecting where the program installs to, but usually not. The default `Administrator` account should never be used and should always remain disabled since it's SID is well-known. Best security practice is to have a normal user & second user apart of the `Administrators` group only, but folks often place their user within the `Administrators` group

Comment: I was trying to install an older Photoshop version. I installed it fine. But when I clicked on either the desktop shortcut or the start menu shortcut, nothing happened. No error. Just nothing. So I decided to try Run as Administrator, and it worked just fine. But the account I used to install and to try to run it has administrator privileges.

I have actually used the Administrator account before. No one is getting in my system. Remote desktop is the first thing I turn off and I just assumed the first thing anyone who changes any settings turns off unless/until they need it.